# Reproducing property of Szegő kernel

Tags: complex-analysis, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I have an embarrassingly basic question about the Szegő kernel on the Hardy space $H^2$ over the right half plane.  It seems I have forgotten as much complex analysis as I ever knew...

A kernel $k(s, z)$ is said to satisfy the reproducing property if
$$
\langle f, k(s, \cdot) \rangle = f(s).
$$

On $H^2$, the inner product is
$$
\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(j\omega) \overline{g(j\omega)}d\omega,
$$

and $k(s, z)$ is known to be the Szegő kernel, $1/(2\pi(z + \bar s))$.

My question is: how does one prove that $k(s, z)$ has the reproducing property?  Plugging into the inner product, I want to show that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(j\omega)}{2\pi(s - j\omega)}d\omega = f(s).
$$
I guess this follows from the residue theorem, but I can't see why the residue of $f(z)/(2\pi(s - \bar z))$ is $f(s)/2j\pi$...

**Edit:** it seems the only issue was that I wasn't orienting the boundary of the right half plane positively (counter-clockwise).  By the residue theorem:
$$
2\pi j \operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{f(z)}{z-s}\right) = \int_{\partial \mathbb{C}^+} \frac{f(j\omega)}{j\omega - s}d(j\omega)\\
f(s) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\infty^{-\infty} \frac{f(j\omega)}{j\omega - s} d\omega\\
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{f(j\omega)}{2\pi(s - j\omega)} d\omega\\
= \langle f, k(s, \cdot) \rangle.
$$

Comment: I found this [link](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analysis/Tasty_Bits_of_Several_Complex_Variables_(Lebl)/05%3A_Integral_Kernels/5.02%3A_The_Bergman_Kernel) on SearchOnMath. Did it Example  5.2.1 helps?

Comment: I don't think you have your inner product right as the integral should be $d\theta$

Comment: Thanks @JoséClaudineiFerreira, that did indeed point me in the right direction.  I believe the solution I just provided in my edit is correct - such a minor issue!

Comment: @Conrad, thanks for the comment.  I don't understand what $\theta$ is..?  I'm sure the functional I have written is an inner product on $H^2$ though (also cross-checked with Partington, "Linear Operators and Linear Systems").